# UWP project : Registration of the App faileed. (0x80073cf6)

Tags: uwp

Registration of the app failed.  (0x80073cf6)

I am simply Debugging my project on LocalMachine with Solution Platforms x86. Building of project is done but when it starts Deploying, it says Registration of the app failed.
What I have to do to Debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are having trouble with deploying UWP app on X86 platform . 
here are some solutions :

1. Try to use X64 debugging maybe you can debug it.
2. Try to Create a new RAW project and see is the problem presents in a new project (maybe Visual Studio problem you can update it from programs and features) .
3. Check All Settings -> Update and Security -> For Developers, Make sure Developer mode is enabled (for both PC and Phone) it must be enabled.
4. If you have problem in deploying on a phone run task manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc) click more details at the bottom of window then navigate to services tab and type 'ipo' and find IPOverUSBSvc and run it, if it running maybe restarting it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue,
FINALLY got to fix it.
The error lies in Package.AppManifest.

```
<Properties>
<DisplayName>Name</DisplayName>
<PublisherDisplayName>Other Name</PublisherDisplayName>
<Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
</Properties>
```

In the app manifest file, change the "Name" to anything else. And it'll work.
That is it.
If that gives you issues, try creating an empty project and take its app manifest, remove the store association key, in the manifest make sure the key points to the local temporary one.